# Python UDP socket resend data if no data recieved

Tags: python, python-sockets

I want to send some data to a sensor and if the python script doesn't receive the data I want the receive function to timeout and resend the data.

```
def subscribe():
   UDP_IP = "192.168.1.166"
   UDP_PORT = 10000
   MESSAGE = '6864001e636caccf2393730420202020202004739323cfac202020202020'.decode('hex')
   print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
   print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
   print "message:", MESSAGE
   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
   sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
   recieve_data = recieve()
   if recieve_data == subscribe_recieve_on or recieve_data == subscribe_recieve_off:
       logging.info('Subscribition to light successful')
   else:
       logging.info('Subscribition to light unsuccessful')

def recieve():
   UDP_IP = "192.168.1.118"
   UDP_PORT = 10000
   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP    
   sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
   data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
   return data.encode('hex')

subscribe()
```

At the moment it gets stuck in the receive function if it doesn't receive any data:

```
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

However I want it to timeout after e.g. 2 seconds and rerun the subscribe() function.

I've tried using a while true statement with a timeout and try/exception however I get a port currently in use even when closing the port. Also feel this way is messy.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the "currently in use" exception because you are recreating the sockets every time you call either of those functions, without closing them first.

Try creating the sockets beforehand. The response might come before the receiving socket is created in which case the packet is just going to be rejected.

Then you should try only the `sendto`-`recvfrom` calls in a loop.

Also you either need to set a timeout with [settimeout](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) on the receiving socket so it does not get blocked then catch the timeout exception or use a polling mechanism like [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) or [poll](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.poll) to check whether you have received any data.